# The style.php file inside theme-engine folder has other content on FTP

Tags: php, themes, css, ftp

I would like to change one image that is apparently still hosted on HTTP on my client's website so that it will be re-uploaded on HTTPS.

Using the *Inspect* feature of my Chrome browser, I spotted the file and it seems to be coming from a file referenced in a link tag with the following structure (altered slightly here for security reasons):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='SAMPLETHEME-theme-css-css' href='https://www.EXAMPLE.com/wp-content/themes/MYTHEME-child/lib/theme-engine/style.php?ver=4.9.13' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

When I open the above file in my browser, it seems to be a CSS file and I can see where this old image is located and that it has an HTTP address, which needs to change.

After failing to find the file in the admin panel, I got access to the FTP location of the host. Inside the FTP, I looked for the corresponding folder under `SAMPLETHEME-child` and then navigate to `/lib/theme-engine/` to find `style.php`. And I do find the file. Except that it does not have the same content as when I opened in the browser.

Does this .php file simply generate another new file when run? At least that's what I have gathered from its code. Below is what the file contains. But the image I am looking for I am still yet to find!

```
<?php
/**
 * Set header
 */
header( "Content-type: text/css", true );

/**
 * Set constants
 */
define( 'STYLESHEET_FILENAME', 'style.css' );
define( 'STYLESHEET_DEV_PATH', 'dev/' );

/**
 * Generates a CSS file based on different settings
 * @return string
 */
function generate_css() {
    /**
     * If merged stylesheet exists, load - else create a new file.
     */
    if ( file_exists( STYLESHEET_FILENAME ) ) {
        return file_get_contents( STYLESHEET_FILENAME );
    } else {

        /*
         *  Load WordPress core
         */
        define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
        $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
        require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

        /**
         * Prepare new merged stylesheet
         */
        $output = "";
        $files  = scandir( STYLESHEET_DEV_PATH );
        foreach ( $files as $file ) {
            // Parse CSS file
            $data = parse_file( $file );
            // Parse font variables
            $data = parse_font_style( $data );
            // Compress CSS and add to queue
            $output .= compress( $data );
        }

        /**
         * If production is running, save file
         */
        if ( get_option( 'getup_theme_production', false ) == true ) {
            file_put_contents( STYLESHEET_FILENAME, $output );
        }

        return $output;
    }
}

/**
 * Parse file
 *
 * @param $filename
 *
 * @return string
 */
function parse_file( $filename ) {
    $ext = pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    if ( $ext == 'css' ) {
        $data = file_get_contents( STYLESHEET_DEV_PATH . $filename );

        /** Logic to parse variables **/

        return $data;
    }
}

/**
 * Compress CSS file
 *
 * @param $buffer string
 *
 * @return string
 */
function compress( $buffer ) {
    /* remove comments */
    $buffer = preg_replace( '!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer );
    /* remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc. */
    $buffer = str_replace( array( "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    ' ), '', $buffer );

    return $buffer;
}

/**
 * Parse and process font style variables
 *
 * @param $data
 *
 * @return string
 */
function parse_font_style( $data ) {
    $font_family = get_option( 'getup_theme_font_family', "'BRANDFILE', serif" );
    $font        = get_option( 'getup_theme_font', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' );

    $search  = array( '$font-family$', '$font$' );
    $replace = array( $font_family, $font );
    $data    = str_replace( $search, $replace, $data );

    return $data;
}

echo generate_css();
```

Comment: You don't need to reupload a file to get HTTPS, you can just use the `https` URL, however, that file looks like it loads in `style.css` and does things to it. I would keep in mind that having standalone files like this in a theme or plugin that the browser loads directly is dangerous and insecure. A good example of a file that does this is timthumb.php which had the major security scare a few years ago.  What is `/lib/theme-engine`? If you're trying to understand how a 3rd party theme works you should contact their support, 3rd party theme support is offtopic here

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just need to replace `http` with `https` there. But apart from that, I thought Wordpress themes follow a specific structure. Any tips on how we can reach the source containing this image is appreciated.

Comment: WP themes have a `functions.php`, a `style.css` and an `index.php`. You can use the template hierarchy to add additional templates, but beyond that there is no standard or convention other than what you choose. I've been working with WP since 2009 and I've never seen a theme before that has a `lib/theme-engine` folder. Have you tried just using your editor to search the entire folder? If the location of the image URL is what you're asking for then it's impossible to answer the question without being handed a full copy of the code